# is it possible to track only a folder in a git branch?

Tags: github, git-branch, github-pages

I don't know if this makes sense or not...

I have a main private git repository where I do all the coding. And I setup another public git to only publish the public results (some of my original data are sensitive information). I have all the results ready in one of the folder within the private git.

So, is it possible to make a branch (github-pages) of the public git track only the result folder of my private git?

Or do you all have a better workflow for this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible

You could do something like this:

1) move the private folder temporarily to another place

2) create a new repo (you should do this to remove any log from old commits that could expose private files in the public branch) and include on the master branch only public files (by now)

```
    git init
    git add . 
    git commit -m 'adding public files to repo'
```

2) create and checkout a new branch named public_stable

```
    git checkout -b public_stable
```

3) create a .gitignore file with the line '/your-private-folder-name/.' in public_stable branch, to exclude those files from your public branch

for example, on a linux box...

```
    touch .gitignore && echo '/your-private-folder/*' >> .gitignore
```

next...

```
    git add .gitignore
    git commit -m 'this branch will ignore files located on private folder'
```

4) Go back to master and create a new branch private_stable from master

```
    git checkout master
    git checkout -b private_stable
```

4) now you can move back the private folder to your project

```
    git add /your-private-folder-name/.
    git commit -m 'added private files'
```

5) After this, you will have two main branches to work on: public_stable and private_stable

6) To work on your private files you should branch from private_stable to create separate work in progress from stable work.

from private_stable...

```
   git checkout -b private_issue
```

and once you are done on private_issue you can merge the changes to private_stable

And you could apply the same workflow for public_* branches

That way you can isolate public from private contents.

Master will have all files but you should avoid merging the .gitignore located in public_* branches to master or private_ branches.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a branch, I would recommend simply removing everything but that folder from the branch and committing. As it appears that you only want that in that branch anyway, this shouldn't have an impact on your workflow.